# Import Date in proper format from Excel to SQL Server through OPENROWSET query

Tags: sql-server, excel, openrowset

I am trying to import huge data without any data loss from excel sheet to SQL Server. The excel sheet has few columns with mixed data types and few column with dates. I have prepared a sample file as seen in the first image below.

[image: SampleData]

**First Try**

When I try to import through OPENROWSET query with `HDR=YES`, **data loss occurred under first column**. Second column got imported fine. Please refer image below.

[image]

**Second Try**

When I try to import through OPENROWSET with `HDR=NO`, data imported fine under first column without any data loss, but second column got imported only with time whereas **date was not imported**. Please refer image below.

[image]

**Edit 1:Third Try**

After extensive internet search, I tried editing registry **TypeGuessRows**=1048576 according to [this microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/initializing-the-microsoft-excel-driver?tabs=office-2016). But this worked for the smaller data. But issue still persists with huge data. I have shared the data where you can test with it. [Please download the excel file to test from this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WR9k9GtEFhaIORwLBoVGqEHK9hR0xsSc/view?usp=sharing) and if it works please share the solution. In the excel file which I have shared in the link, please note that the **row A1000011** has **alphabetic chars which is not getting imported to SQL Server** with `HDR=YES` method. If I use `HDR=NO`, **date is not getting imported**. Both column data is significant for me.

> I need solution to import all data with any kind of formatting from excel to
>   SQL Server without any data loss. Please advise.

**Note**

1. I should not open the excel file `manually` and change formatting.
   This step is not allowed.
2. Not all files are in same structure. I am getting many files with
   many columns with different structure. So I cannot create a standard
   table with data types fixed.

Comment: `HDR=YES` indicates the first row is a header.  Please add the current table definition to your question.

Comment: Export your excel data to a different format.  I personally prefer tab-delimited `.csv` files because people don't often include tabs within their free-form data fields, but you can do whatever you want.  Excel, in my opinion, is one of the worst "raw formats" to import data from as it does all manner of custom formatting under the covers which often throws off SSIS packages or, as you're seeing, direct TSQL queries using `OPENROWSET`.

Comment: After changing *TypeGuessRows*, did you restart the SQL Server instance? I tested this and the setting change had no effect until I restarted the SQL Server instance.

Comment: @HandyD - I restarted my system, but still not working

Comment: @HandyD - I restarted my system and SQL Server instance, but still not working. Did you try with the file which I have shared?

Comment: Yes I did. What version of SQL Server? I am using SQL Server 2017 but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @HandyD  - I am using SQL Server 2014 and the import is not working. Data loss occurring from 1000010 th row in SQL Server with 'HDR=YES' and TypeGuessRows=1048576 changed in Registry.